# Вопрос по форматированию ответа из БД

Tags: c#

Есть метод:

```
public string FormatName(AroInfo aro)
{
    return $"({ aro.Aro }) { aro.Name }";
}
```

Есть ридер из БД:

```
using (OracleDataReader OraReader = OraCmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (!OraReader.HasRows) return result;
    while (OraReader.Read())
    {
        var aro = new AroInfo();
        aro.Aro = Convert.ToString(OraReader.GetValue(2));
        aro.Name = Convert.ToString(OraReader.GetValue(3));
        int indexStatus = stats.FindIndex(x => x.ARO == aro.Aro);
        aro.Status = indexStatus;

        if (OraReader.GetInt32(0) == 1 || OraReader.IsDBNull(4))
        {
            TreeNode node = new TreeNode(OraReader.GetString(3));
            node.Tag = aro;
            tree.Nodes.Add(node);
            ht.Add(OraReader.GetInt32(1), node);
        }
```

Мне нужно чтобы `Tree` выводило номер `aro` и его `Name`, сейчас выводит только `Name`

Comment: `var node = new TreeNode(FormatName(aro));`